# PHP Variable in a Class array

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, variables

I am trying to call a variable to add to an array within a class, but I keenp getting unexpected T_VARIABLE error when I try.

```
class MB_API {
    $SName = 'Test';
    $PWD = 'test';
    $SiteID = '10';
    protected $client;
    protected $sourceCredentials = array(
        "SourceName"=>$SName, 
        "Password"=>$PWD, 
        "SiteIDs"=>array($SiteID)
    );
};
```

The variables can be set within the class or outside, it doesn't really matter. They will be set by a pull from a database.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include the entire error message please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default variable values need to be **compile time literals** (They need to be constant *before* the script runs, basically, a `"literal string"`, a number `42` or an array of constant values `array(1, 2, 3)`), meaning, they can't have a dynamic value (such as another variable).

A better way would be to use a constructor:

```
protected $sourceCredentials = []; //PHP5.4 and above syntax, synonymous to array()

public function __construct(array $sourceCredentials) {
    $this->sourceCredentials = $sourceCredentials;
}
```

Note that this way, it's up to the caller (the code that instantiated the object) to pass in the array of credentials from the outside. There are different ways of doing so, but this is considered best practice.

Comment: To expand in a non technical way it means that `$sourceCredentials` can only be set as an empty array. You will have to fill it from within a method of `MB_API`

Comment: @CarlMarkham: Expanded and added an example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your variable value in constructor.

For best practice you use like this:

```
class MB_API {

    private $Sname;
    private $PWD;
    private $SiteID;
    protected $client;
    protected $sourceCredentials;

    public function __construct() {

        // Set your default Values here

        $this->Sname = "Test";
        $this->PWD = 'test';
        $this->SiteID - '10';

        $this->sourceCredentials = array(
            "SourceName" => $this->SName,
            "Password" => $this->PWD,
            "SiteIDs" => array($this->SiteID)
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two different "$sname" - one is `$SName` and another is `$Sname`

Comment: PHP is case insensitive, that's not the problem.

Comment: Ahhh, so it is. Getting my languages confused!